# Prevent Outlook from displaying plain text emails with formatting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, plaintext

Our app sends plain text emails.  They appear fine in some email clients but the ASCII/text table lines are distorted in Outlook 2010.  How can you force Outlook to view these as plain text without any formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.  Have to change your plain text font to a monospaced font such as Courier New.

Described [here](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-change-the-font-on-incoming-messages/):

- File, Options, Mail, Stationery and Fonts
- Set "Composing and reading plain text messages" font to Courier New.

More info [here](http://www.dailytech.com/Microsoft+Office+Corner+How+to+Paste+Ascii+Art+Into+OneNote/article23987.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Email Security > Read all Standard Mail in Plain Text
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  Outlook is already reading it as plain text but it's applying a non monospaced font.  Have to change that and you're good.   See my answer.